# В чем смотреть разницу между исходниками (текстом)?

Tags: git, svn, поиск-программ, tfs

Подскажите программу для анализа текста, аналогичную тем, что используются в системах контроля версий.

Иногда необходимо сравнить два участка кода, найти и проанализировать различия. Конечно, есть вариант закоммитить один в SVN, подменить другим и смотреть различия. Но всё же не хочется мусорить в истории коммитов.

Comment: `diff`, вероятно?

Comment: Запрос _code compare_ в поисковике. https://www.devart.com/codecompare/ https://www.diffnow.com

Comment: SublimeText умеет такое делать - открываешь подобный код в соседних вкладках и он указывает на отличия

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут скорее не "где найти", а "какой инструмент использовать".

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, тогда причина закрытия чуть иная: «Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе». по этому поводу у меня возражений нет.

Comment: Если кого-то интересует такая вещь с целью интеграции в собственную программу, рекомендую взглянуть на [`diff-match-patch` от Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).

Answer (score 5):

Даже не знаю, почему все предлагают онлайн утилиты. Если нужно сравнить пять-десять строк, то это можно и ручками, а если нужно мегабайтные куски (не объязательно прямо код, есть много чего, что нужно сравнивать), то как по мне, только нативные приложения. А их вагон и тележка. Платные я не вижу смысла рассматривать, так как есть  нормальные бесплатные. Хотя говорят, что [araxis](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en) просто чудо, но я его не использовал.

- [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). Есть под линукс и винду, под виндой маленький недостаток - требует установленного питона и ещё немного библиотек. Под линуксом ставится с репозитория. Кроме как сравнить файлы, умеет работать с основной массой систем контроля версий (даже коммитить). Я лично пользуюсь и запускаю его как `meld .` в каталоге с проектом. Сразу видно какие файлы изменились.
- [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=ru). Пока доступен только под винду, но обещают скоро и под линукс (кроссплатформенный). Но его интерфейс как то чуточку "староват".
- [diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/). Виндовс/Линукс. Ничего особого не увидел, но вот "сеточка" в коде как то не то. Но это на любителя.

Answer (score 3):

в программах контроля версий используется либо «нормальный» (`--normal`, по умолчанию), либо «унифицированный» (`--unified`, `-u`) форматы [программы *diff*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html):

```
$ diff файл1 файл2
1c1
< qwerty
---
> qwerty1

$ diff -u файл1 файл2
--- "файл1" 2016-07-28 10:48:41.337854383 +0300
+++ "файл2" 2016-07-28 10:48:54.073854155 +0300
@@ -1 +1 @@
-qwerty
+qwerty1
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть хороший плагин [Compare](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/) для [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Я этим пользуюсь. Радует что онлайн, плюс поделится можно
https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: если пользоваться IDE, например Webstorm (да и все продукты JetBrains), там есть `Compare With` (CTRL + D) на файле, и выбираешь файл для сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас установлен TortoiseSVN или TortoiseGIT то вы можете использовать для сравнения TortoiseMerge, даже если файлы не версированы.

Answer (score 0):

Это целый сектор программ. На вики есть достаточно исчерпывающий список с перечислением особенностей и фич: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools