# Как закрепить адрес источника пакетов, уходящих с указанного интерфейса?

Tags: debian, сеть, ip, route

На итерфейсе eth0 поднят ряд ip. Допустим файл /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 100.100.100.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 100.100.100.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 100.100.100.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Если посмотреть таблицу маршрутизации, то видим следующие записи.

```
$ ip route show
default via 100.100.100.1 dev eth0
100.100.100.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.100.100.102
```

Задача в том, чтобы всегда значение **src 100.100.100.102** было тем ip, который я укажу (и было постоянным). Я могу это сделать вручную, через команду `ip`, но это будет лишь до первой перезагрузки сервера или вызова команды `service networking reload`

Как это сделать грамотно, учитывая что количество ip может быть более 100 на одном интерфейсе?

И если создавать таблицу маршрутизации, опять же через команду `ip` ,то она существует тоже лишь до первой перезагрузки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> eth0:1 eth0:2

т.н. *network interface aliases* в сетевой подсистеме программы *linux* неактуальны уже лет 15-16. ниже я привожу нормальную конфигурацию без этого «тяжёлого наследия». но если хотите, просто дополните конфигурацию *alias-ами*.

> Задача в том, что я хочу, что бы всегда значение src 100.100.100.102 было тем ip который я укажу (и было постоянным).

так и укажите это явно (последняя строка):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 100.100.100.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
up ip a a 100.100.100.101/24 dev $IFACE
up ip a a 100.100.100.102/24 dev $IFACE
up ip r c 100.100.100.0/24 dev $IFACE src 100.100.100.102
```

использованные сокращения (можно писать и полностью, просто так короче):

- `ip a a` = `ip address add`
- `ip r c` = `ip route change`

---

по поводу «дополнить конфигурацию *alias-ами*».

если уж они так необходимы, то проще всего указать эти *alias-ы* (в терминологии программы *ip* — метки, *labels*) непосредственно аргументами программы *ip*:

```
ip a a ... label $IFACE:0
```

Comment: Стоит расшифровать `a a` и `r ch` для потомков. И для поиска.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, расшифровал.

Comment: На мой взгляд сокращения хороши когда команды вручную набираешь. А в файле конфига (и в ответе) лучше что бы всё было понятно

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в целом согласен с вашим мнением, и частенько сам привожу и краткую и длинную форму опции/параметра. [например: `-u` и `--unified`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549402/178576).

Comment: Спасибо @alexanderbarakin ! Ваш вариант действительно хорош! А где я могу почитать более подробно про используемые переменные вроде $IFACE

Comment: @никитамерзликин, `man interfaces`